# Is it possible put Waze in a movable tile window, the same way Google Maps can?

Tags: google-maps, navigation, waze

Is it possible put Waze in a movable tile window, the same way Google Maps can as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Not without any dev work on Waze's side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is picture-in-picture (PiP) mode, and Waze has not supported it yet.**

Google Maps v9.60 added support for PiP mode [in August 2018](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/28/google-maps-v9-60-brings-usable-picture-picture-mode-prepares-adding-personal-notes-locations-food-reviews-apk-teardown-download/). Also, as per [the official Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture),

> Your app controls when the current activity enters PiP mode. Here are some examples:
>
> - An activity can enter PiP mode when the user taps the home button or swipes up to home. This is how Google Maps continues to display directions while the user runs another activity at the same time.
> - [...]

The support of this feature can be seen on the Google Maps' app info where it shows "Picture-in-picture" under the "Advanced" section, whereas Waze only has "Display over other apps".

[image] [image]

<sup>Left/Top: Google Maps | Right/Bottom: Waze</sup>

As explained in the documentation, supporting PiP needs additional development on the app side, thus it is not something that can be enabled by the end user.

This feature has been suggested to Waze on November 2018, [Activate "picture in picture" (PIP).](https://waze.uservoice.com/forums/59223-waze-suggestion-box/suggestions/35878879-activate-picture-in-picture-pip). However, the latest status is "Not right now" since August 2022.

---

On the other hand, some vendors have their own customization, like [Samsung's pop-up view](https://www.reddit.com/r/waze/comments/w26ern/android_alternatives_to_pop_up_view/) that may be acceptable as an alternative.