# How to stop vlc from resizing on home button touch

Tags: video, vlc

I have vlc installed on my Android phone running Android version 11, whenever there is a video playing and then I hit the home button it resizes and continues to play the video in Pip mode, I have checked in the VLC video settings and I have confirmed that  PiP is disabled. How do I force VLC to not resize whenever I hit either the intentions button or the home button?

Comment: I don't use VLC, but could you check the App Info settings whether there is a Picture-in-picture option there? (Similar question: [Is it possible put Waze in a movable tile window, the same way Google Maps can?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/248916/44325))

Comment: In the system settings or in the application settings?

Comment: From the system settings, e.g. long-tapping the app icon and selecting the circled-"i" icon.

Comment: Let me try, disabling it from the system sounds like a great idea

Comment: it worked, i found the setting and prevented vlc from using picture in picture,  Thanks

Comment: Good to know, feel free to self-answer it :)